# Time series prediction completely off using ESN

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, python, predictive-models

I am attempting to predict closing prices based on closing prices extracted from OHLC data from a two-month window with 10 minute intervals (roughly 8600 data points). For this attempt, I am building an echo-state network (ESM), following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-stock-prices-with-echo-state-networks-f910809d23d4).

With the code below, the prediction is fairly worthless. It looks like noise around an arbitrary average, which does not even resemble the latest data point in the training data. This is nothing close to what the ESN in the tutorial managed at this point. I have tried to alter the results by manually tweaking the hyperparameters `n_reservoir`, `sparsity`, and `spectral_radius`, but all to no avail. During a 4-week course last spring ESNs were briefly touched upon, but not enough for me to understand where I am at fault.

[image]

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pyESN import ESN
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

df = pd.read_csv('path')
data = df['close'].to_numpy()

n_reservoir = 500
sparsity = 0.2
spectral_radius = 1.2
noise = .0005

esn = ESN(n_inputs = 1,
          n_outputs = 1,
          n_reservoir = n_reservoir,
          sparsity=sparsity,
          spectral_radius = spectral_radius,
          noise=noise)

trainlen = 7000
future = 10
futureTotal = 100
pred_tot = np.zeros(futureTotal)

for i in range(0,futureTotal,future):
    pred_training = esn.fit(np.ones(trainlen),data[i:trainlen+i])
    prediction = esn.predict(np.ones(future))
    pred_tot[i:i+future] = prediction[:,0]

plt.plot(range(0,trainlen+futureTotal),data[0:trainlen+futureTotal],'b',label="Data", alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(range(trainlen,trainlen+futureTotal),pred_tot,'k',  alpha=0.8, label='Free Running ESN')

lo,hi = plt.ylim()
plt.plot([trainlen,trainlen],[lo+np.spacing(1),hi-np.spacing(1)],'k:', linewidth=4)

plt.title(r'Ground Truth and Echo State Network Output')
plt.xlabel(r'Time', labelpad=10)
plt.ylabel(r'Price ($)', labelpad=10)
plt.legend(loc='best')
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```